# Resume Fragments from another activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have two activities named Home activity and Salad Menu activity. Home Activity contains seven fragments and one of the fragment named Menu Categories Fragment has four images, text below first image is Salad menu, when user clicks on salad menu new activity named Salad Menu Activity is started.

I want that, when user clicks on back button home activity must start and the same fragment should start from which salad menu activity was started that is menu categories fragment in home activity. I want this to happen with every activity, for example, if user starts a new activity from your orders fragment and when he clicks back button than again your orders fragment must resume and so on with all other fragments and activities.

Home Activity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    if(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).isLoggedIn()){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    Fragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
    if(fragment != null){

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.screen_area, fragment);

        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }else if (id == R.id.action_signout){
        SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).logout();
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class));
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.

    Fragment fragment = null;

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Home was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_menu_categories) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Menu categories was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        fragment = new MenuCategoriesFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_your_orders) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Your orders was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        fragment = new YourOrdersFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_your_favorites) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Your favorite was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        fragment = new YourFavoritesFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_hot_deals) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Hot deals was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        fragment = new HotDealsFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_notifications) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Notifications was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        fragment = new NotificationsFragment();
    } else if(id == R.id.nav_profile){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Profile was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        fragment = new ProfileFragment();
    } else if(id == R.id.nav_logout){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Logout was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).logout();
        startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, SignInActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    if(fragment != null){

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.screen_area, fragment);

        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

MenuCategoriesFragment.java

```
private LinearLayout linearLayoutSaladMenu, linearLayoutNoddlesCategories, linearLayoutPotatoMenu, linearLayoutBurgerMenu;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu_categories, null);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    getActivity().setTitle("Menu Categories");

    linearLayoutSaladMenu = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.salad_menu);
    linearLayoutNoddlesCategories = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.noddles_categories);
    linearLayoutPotatoMenu = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.potato_menu);
    linearLayoutBurgerMenu = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.burger_menu);

    linearLayoutSaladMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SaladMenuActivity.class));
        }
    });

    linearLayoutNoddlesCategories.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Noddles categories was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    linearLayoutPotatoMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Potato menu was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    linearLayoutBurgerMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Burger menu was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

SaladMenuActivity.class

```
List<SaladMenuItem> saladMenuItemsList;
ListView listViewSaladMenu;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_salad_menu);

    saladMenuItemsList = new ArrayList<>();
    listViewSaladMenu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewSaladMenu);

    saladMenuItemsList.add(new SaladMenuItem(R.drawable.fried_rice_with_sauce, "Fried Rice with Sauce", "$30.00"));
    saladMenuItemsList.add(new SaladMenuItem(R.drawable.vegetable_salad, "Vegetable Salad", "$12.00"));

    SaladMenuListAdapter adapter = new SaladMenuListAdapter(this, R.layout.salad_menu_list, saladMenuItemsList);

    listViewSaladMenu.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Use `EventBus` or Local `Broadcast` .

Answer (score 0):

Try `onBackPressed()` and inside `onBackPressed()` start the activity where you want to go..use `onBackPressed()`. I think that will solve your problem